# What is a good antonym for "vouch"?

Tags: antonyms

Example context: "I vouch for this user."

What would be a good antonym/opposite sentence?

I've seen people use "I devouch this user" on forum boards, but it doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 6):

*Disavow* seems a good fit.

> VERB
>
> Deny any responsibility or support for.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disavow

Example of usage: "I *disavow* this user."